Hot swap CAN terminating resistor?
In my application I would like to dynamically configure the terminating resistor on a CANopen bus. The board I am designing is in a closed case IP67 and the customer could either use the board as an intermediate device on the bus or a master node.
Two naive solutions exists:

Micro dip switch to enable/disable the 120 Ohm resistor (not compatible with my IP67 use case)
Have a custom connector with a 120 Ohm in it that can be used to terminate the bus.

Both solution would require manual operations. I would like an easier solution where the terminal resistor can be enabled/disabled programmatically during commissioning.
Using a miniature reel relay is too big and it consumes current, so I am thinking about an analog switch such as this one:

https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ts5a3166.pdf
Would it be suitable for such application?

Does the answer Add or remove 120 Ohm from the CAN circuit using Microcontroller help? It references a TI reference design.

Pulse relays don't consume current after toggled to correct state.

@Justme Relays simply can't be used, they are too slow and add too many uncertainties, potentially causing tons of CAN error frames and killing the whole bus. See my answer in that link.

Why is resistor inside an external connector not an option? Assuming all nodes have two connectors for CAN in/out (M12 probably?), you're gonna need to plug the last connector anyway, or you won't get IP67.
